# Space of stochastic process $\mathcal M (\mathcal C [0, T], E)$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

A simple notation question, what is the precise definition of the space $\mathcal M (\mathcal C [0, T], E)$ ($\mathcal M^p (\mathcal C [0, T], E)$) in the context of stochastic processes where $E$ is a banach space ($\mathbb R ^d$ or $\mathbb L^p_{\lambda}(\Gamma)$ for example)?

In [the article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.2414.pdf) I read, this notation is introduced without definitions, seeming so to be pretty standard. 
In addition what is the mean of 
$\mathcal M (\mathcal C( [0, T], E))$ and what is the difference between the previous space?

Thanks in advance

Comment: At what page are you encountering this notation?